# Why unicode character is printing even using 1 byte to handling it

Tags: c, linux, shell, terminal, signals

I am doing a school project and I came across something that shouldn't work in theory.

I need to create two programs where one communicates with the other through unix signals, I will call them client and server, I pass a message in my client's argv, break each char into bit and send to the server

The idea is to use bitwise communication (Something simple and rudimentary, if the bit is 0 I send SIGUSR1 to the server PID using the kill system call, if it is 1 I send SIGUSR2.

```c
#client send a char to server
int send_sig(int pid, unsigned char b)
{
    int a;

    a = 0;
    while (a < 8)
    {
        if (b & 1)
            kill(pid, SIGUSR2);
        else
            kill(pid, SIGUSR1);
        b = b >> 1;
        a++;
        usleep(1000);
    }
    return (0);
}
```

the problem is when I use unicode characters, the argv will always be a string (an array of char) so when I pass some unicode character it will vary from 1 to 4 bytes, even so the process continues normal, the problem happens on my server side where I get these bits

The way I structured my code is that I need to print one bit at a time (which is acceptable since in theory a char in C is equivalent to one byte) but even when passing 4 byte unicode characters, printing them one at a time it keeps working (it's like Russian roulette, it breaks sometimes and works normally sometimes)

```c
# Server receiving the 
unsigned char   reverse(unsigned char b)
{
    b = (b & 0xF0) >> 4 | (b & 0x0F) << 4;
    b = (b & 0xCC) >> 2 | (b & 0x33) << 2;
    b = (b & 0xAA) >> 1 | (b & 0x55) << 1;
    return (b);
}

void    signal_handler(int sig, siginfo_t *p_info, void *ucontext)
{
    static unsigned int     a = 0;
    static unsigned int     b = 0;

    a <<= 1;
    if (sig == SIGUSR2)
        a++;
    b++;
    if (b == 8)
    {
        b = 0;
        ft_printf("%c\0", reverse(a));
    }
    p_info = p_info;
    ucontext = ucontext;
}
```

Why this behavior happens ? wasn't it just for it to break and print something wrong ?

Expeculations:

- the way I print on stdout without NULL byte make the shell and terminal interpreter a whole byte without losing the UTF-8 map
- The unicode fitt in char (*But this is impossible I guess)*

reproduce this behavior with theses code:

```c
#client.c file
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
void send_sig(int pid, char b)
{
    int a = 0;
    printf("%c", b);
    while (a < 8)
    {
        if (b & 1)
            kill(pid, SIGUSR2);
        else
            kill(pid, SIGUSR1);
        b >>= 1;
        a++;
        usleep(500);
    }
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *s = "";

    while (*s++ != '\0')
        send_sig(atoi(argv[1]), *s);

}
```

```c
#server.c file
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

unsigned char   reverse(unsigned char b)
{
    b = (b & 0xF0) >> 4 | (b & 0x0F) << 4;
    b = (b & 0xCC) >> 2 | (b & 0x33) << 2;
    b = (b & 0xAA) >> 1 | (b & 0x55) << 1;
    return (b);
}

void    signal_handler(int sig, siginfo_t *p_info, void *ucontext)
{
    static unsigned int     a = 0;
    static unsigned int     b = 0;

    a <<= 1;
    if (sig == SIGUSR2)
        a++;
    b++;
    if (b == 8)
    {
        b = 0;
        a = reverse(a);
        write(1, &a, 1);
    }
    p_info = p_info;
    ucontext = ucontext;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct sigaction    act;

    act.sa_sigaction = signal_handler;
    sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
    act.sa_flags = 0;
    sigaction(SIGUSR1, &act, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGUSR2, &act, NULL);
    printf("The server pid: %d\n", getpid());
    while (1)
        usleep(300);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your description of the problem. How are you calling `send_sig()` when the argument is 4-byte character? Are you calling it in a loop for each byte? The signal handler will only show the first byte, because it only prints something when `b==8`, not every multiple of 8.

Comment: Yep, I'm calling it in a loop for each byte and passing the current char to the send_sig(), the problem came with a unicode char like a emoji is sending to the server, in theory, my handle print only 1 bite at the time ->  -> 11110000 10011111 10100100 10101000
in the first I print 11110000 and later 10011111 ...
and this no make sense to work and print the unicode correctly I guess

Comment: Oops, I didn't notice that you reset `b = 0` when it reaches 8.

Comment: Please post a [mre]

Comment: UTF-8 is a variable-length encoding. Some characters fit in 1 byte, some fit in 2 bytes, some in 3, and some in 4.

Comment: @johmatos it should work if you print 11110000 and then 10011111 and then 10100100 and then 10101000. You can try running `./your_program | od -t x1` or something like that, to print out the hex codes and make sure you're getting the right hex codes

Comment: @Barmar I added the minimal reproducible example

Comment: I don't understand your confusion.  You have a message to send from client to server.  You can subdivide that any number of ways -- bits, bytes, machine words, multibyte code sequences, ... -- but what does that matter?  If you successfully transfer the message in terms of any one of those units, say bits, then you have successfully transferred it in terms of *all* of those units.  So why would you expect a successful transfer to appear not to have been successful?

Comment: Let's put it another way. You seem to think that timing has something to do with it, so do you notice anything strange about the first sentence of this comment?  No?  You can't tell that I paused about one second after typing each character in it? The rest of the message was typed at my usual, much faster speed.  Can you tell the difference?

Comment: Messaging and communication on the client and server work correctly, but I'm trying to understand why unicode cases work correctly because unicode works from 1 to 4 bytes and I am currently working with separate 1 byte printing, breaking the unicode sequence. The consequences of this problem generate a possible bug and incorrect sequence of bytes on output after the bug, run the minimum code a few times and you can see this @JohnBollinger

Comment: You're not getting it, @johmatos.  Your string containing multibyte characters is just as much a string containing all the individual bytes that make up those multibyte characters.  You don't "break" anything by transferring each byte individually, whether the transfer is from client to server or from server to output device.  That's not to say that your signal based messaging protocol is reliable -- it's not.  But the only thing that multibyte characters have to do with that is a larger cross-section for being affected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending unicode bit by bit can be implemented either by sending the 16 (UTF-16) or 32 (UTF-32) bit value (that means a character transmission is always 16 or 32 bits long) or byte by byte. If latter, then the first byte determines the number of bytes (bits) in the transmission. Currently, your server reads only 8 bits and sends the received byte to output, the rest of the (possible multibyte character) bytes are not considered and discarded.

If your server has the first byte (8-bits), then do the following to calculate the number of bytes in the transmission:

```
if (byte < 0x80)
    num_bytes = 1; //single byte, no further read required
else if ((byte & 0xe0) == 0xc0)
    num_bytes = 2; //one more byte to read
else if ((byte & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
    num_bytes = 3; //two more bytes to read
else if ((byte & 0xf8) == 0xf0)
    num_bytes = 4; //three more bytes to read
```

Then, to form a valid utf8 (multibyte) character, read the following (if any) bytes into a char array, e.g. `unsigned char utf8_bytes[4];`

Of course, in order to form a valid null-terminated (printable) string the size of the array has to be `5` and the last byte set to `'\0'`.

---

**Addition**

Your client is sending the bit-sequence (byte: 10101010) as follows:

```
1010101|0 -> SIGUSR1
 101010|1 -> SIGUSR2
  10101|0 -> SIGUSR1
   1010|1 -> SIGUSR2
    101|0 -> SIGUSR1
     10|1 -> SIGUSR2
      1|0 -> SIGUSR1
       |1 -> SIGUSR2
```

So, every time your server is receiving a `SIGUSR2` it has to set the bit at a certain position, which can be easily done like this:

```
if (sig == SIGUSR2)
    byte |= (1 << bit_counter);

++bit_counter;
```

The complete server code could look like this:

```
void signal_handler(int sig, siginfo_t *p_info, void *ucontext)
{
    static unsigned char utf8_bytes[5]; //multibyte storage
    static unsigned char byte = 0; //bitset
    
    static int byte_index  = 0; //current position in the mb storage
    static int bit_counter = 0; //number of bits received
    static int num_bytes   = 1; //total number of bytes of mb character
    
    if (sig == SIGUSR2) //bit: 1
        byte |= (1 << bit_counter); //set the according bit in byte
        
    if (++bit_counter == 8) { //we received 8 bits -> 1 byte
    
        if (byte_index == 0) { //if first byte in sequence
            if (byte < 0x80)
                num_bytes = 1; //single byte, no further read required
            else if ((byte & 0xe0) == 0xc0)
                num_bytes = 2; //one more byte to read
            else if ((byte & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
                num_bytes = 3; //two more bytes to read
            else if ((byte & 0xf8) == 0xf0)
                num_bytes = 4; //three more bytes to read
        }

        //since we completed 1 byte, decrease num_bytes
        if (--num_bytes == 0) { //and if there are no more bytes to read
            utf8_bytes[++byte_index] = '\0'; //make null-terminated string
            //printf("%s\n", utf8_bytes); //do something useful
            byte_index = 0; //reset the byte index
        } else { //we need further reading
            utf8_bytes[byte_index++] = byte; //store the byte
        }
        
        bit_counter = 0; //reset counter
        byte        = 0; //reset byte (set all bits to zero)

    }
    
    p_info = p_info;
    ucontext = ucontext;
}
```